# Proper way to design Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

**[Original Title] : Does an actor need to point directly in use case diagram?**

---

or can I do it like this?

[image: Whole picture Use-Case-Diagram]

in this Use Case Diagram, I want to say that actor can use any use case in the pointed group-of-use-case.

does this kind of thing allowed?

**Edit #1**

The reason why I ask this question, is because when I create this use case there's a lot of line intersecting each other that makes me confuse.

And there's a comment :

> It would be better to split that into smaller diagrams

does it mean like this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit #2**

after reading comment :

> A UseCase specifies a set of actions performed by its subjects, which yields an observable result that is of value for one or more Actors or other stakeholders of each subject.

so I decided to change to this :

[image]

is this how a use case diagram should be?

**Edit #3**

**CONCLUSION**

- An actor should point directly to use case
- Read more the detail about how a Use Case Diagram should be in comment on this question

Comment: Although no one is going to punish you for doing so, I think it is fine.  One thing though is the color scheme is confusing, and the groupings might look better with a venn diagram.

Comment: I think it's rather confusing to show the same actor multiple time on the diagram, and it definitely is not UML. Furthermore I would nog add this much things on a diagram. It would be better to split that into smaller diagrams.

Comment: @ergonaut since there is only 3 actor, so I decided to color it using RGB. So when an use case can be used by 2 actors, I'll just add the color value from the actor.

Comment: @GeertBellekens please check my edited question

Comment: Much better already. Now it is UML compliant and much easier to read. I still don't like your includes and extends relations. The includes seem a bit pointless. Think about the definition of the use case `View Home` Is that really worth a use case?. The extends relations are probably not needed either, and they are definitely in the wrong direction.

Comment: @GeertBellekens my bad, I will fix the direction shortly. About the definition of use case, shouldn't `a use case is something that actor could do with a system` ?

Comment: No, the official definition is: `A UseCase specifies a set of actions performed by its subjects, which yields an observable result that is of value for one or more Actors or other stakeholders of each subject.` In this case I think `View Home` has little or no value to the Actor, and I can imagine that it isn't really a complicated set of actions either. So you can probably safely omit that and maybe add a step or a precondition in your other use cases about he homepage.

Comment: @GeertBellekens where did you get that official definition from? could you please share the link to those statements?

Comment: the UML standard is managed by the Object Management Group (OMG). See http://uml.org for the official specs.

Comment: @GeertBellekens please check my edited question. is that a proper use case should be?

Comment: YES, that is what use cases is about! Well done.

Comment: @GeertBellekens thank you very much! I'll edit question so it includes the conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be UML compliant you can not do that. But I guess one can understand what you are trying to communicate.

As a side note: `Login` is not a business use case. It is a constraint. Also with CRUD use cases I would not separate them but have a `Maintain <object>` instead (which itself is some borderline use case since *maintaining* something is not directly business relevant). You can constrain maintenance operations to certain actors separately.

**Edit** Regarding `Login` (one of my favorites): Use cases are most commonly used to describe business context (exactly as you are doing). So when looking from a business perspective, a `Login` is not a use case, but a simple constraint (you can do the business relevant things only when you are logged in).

[image]

Now for the `Manage/Maintain` use cases. They are on a similar level. Usually the "managing" itself is not directly business related. In many cases the focus on the real business was lost. So instead the reason why you manage something is the real use case (e.g. Correct User Data, Collect User Data). This is quite challenging and I confess that sometimes I also fall back to `Manage`. Most people don't bother but doing a good job requires to think over basics and not adopt bad habits.

Comment: care to explain more about `Maintain <object>` ? also isn't a use case should be `what an actor could do with the system` ?

Comment: please check my edited question. is that a proper use case should be?

Comment: I have added a few infos to my answer.